# Sonata Admin translations with default content

Tags: symfony, localization, translation, sonata-admin

I was able to setup Sonata Admin with translated entities using [Gedmo Doctrine Extensions](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/translation/master/doc/reference/installation.html):

```
# Doctrine Extensions Configuration
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
            blameable: true
            translatable: true

# Sonata Translation Configuration
sonata_translation:
    locales: [en, fr, it]
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    gedmo:
        enabled: true
```

However every time I create a new entity, the translatable fields in the other languages starts empty.

English language selected:

[image]

Italian language selected:

[image]

It becomes **very difficult** to translate items if I don't know what they are in English.

Is there an option so that when I create an entity in English it populates also the entities in the other languages with the same content?

Comment: there is `translation_fallback` option, https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L30 that could maybe help you

Comment: What should it do? I tried setting it to `true` but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Hello @StockBreak! Did you find any solution? I'm facing same problem and trying solving without overriding the sonata create method.

Comment: @Bhaktaraz unfortunately no, the customer accepted this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add fallback option to fields you need:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 *
 * @Gedmo\Translatable(fallback=true)
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess You forget to load the event listener service. 
For each Gedmo extension (Timestampable, Blameable, **Translatable** etc. )  you have to register service in your service container.

**For Translatable:**

```
    ## app/config/services.yml

    services:

        ## ...

        gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ %locale% ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ false ] ]
```

Comment: Simply adding this lines in the services.yml doesn't work. Do I have to change something? Thanks.